# Unbiasedness condition in ordinary kriging and simple kriging

Tags: spatial, prediction, unbiased-estimator

I have this confusion. In ordinary kriging we have used the unbiasedness condition which gave the sum of weights equal to one. However, in the case of simple kriging we have no such conditions why?

I used ordinary kriging and simple kriging in my dataset and I have a huge difference in kriging in predicting the values. AFAIK, simple kriging is a linear regression which ordinary kriging is a constrained linear regression where sum of weights equal to 1.

Comment: Your first paragraph describes the difference between OK and SK.  As such, they are different techniques: asking "why" seems to make as little sense as asking why, say, a Mann-Whitney test is not the same as a t test.  Perhaps you are trying to ask a different question with your "why," maybe one about when SK would be appropriate and when OK would be appropriate to apply.

Comment: @whuber. I mean to say why don't we need unbiasedness condition in simple kriging? Why are we using that in ordinary kriging? Also my ultimate question is when to use which. As in my case, ordinary kriging performed much better than simple kriging, even though my data was generated from a gaussian distribution with mean 0,which is assumed by simple kriging

Comment: You are not using SK in OK: they are different procedures. Few people use SK; in every description I have ever seen, it is clearly stated that SK applies when the process is stationary and *its (global) mean is known.*  That is a rare circumstance. It is no surprise OK performed better than SK because it adapts better to local values. I bet, though, that you used a variogram to do the OK; that's not an appropriate way to model the process with SK.

Comment: @whuber. Thanks for your information. You have been a really helpful person whuber. Thats why stats.stackexchange rocks :)

Answer (score 1):

In SK the sum of weights is one as well as in OK.

The weights given to the samples and the weight given to the mean must sum to one, making the estimate unbiased.

Answer (score 0):

In ordinary kriging, the unknown $\mu$ is updated in each prediction for new location as the control data points is added with every and the newly simulated value. Because the $\mu$ is dependent of location $s$, we don't need to fragment the predictor into the model plus residual $\mu + \delta(s)$. The simulated value at $s_0$ will simply follow $\sum^n_{i=1}\lambda_iZ(s_i)\pm t\sigma_k(s_0)$. Generally, the model could be a polynomial which depends on location. In that case of universal kriging, the predictor should be fragmented into the deterministic part (based on location) and the interpolated residual, so the simulated value at $s_0$ will be as follows : $\sum^{p+1}_{j=1}f_{j-1}(s_0)\beta_{j-1}+\sum^n_{i=1}\lambda_i(Z(s_i)-\sum^{p+1}_{j=1}f_{j-1}(s_i)\beta_{j-1})\pm t\sigma_k(s_0)$

In simple kriging, we regress the mean first only using the sample data, the mean will remain constant along the prediction for the entire domain. The simulated value at $s_0$ will follow $\mu+\sum^n_{i=1}\lambda_i(Z(s_i)-\mu)\pm t\sigma_k(s_0)$.